# class filed of File type in Python

Tags: python, file, class

Hi I am trying to make a Logfile for my class that anything happens to be written in there...

here is how my class looks like

```
class MyClass:
    f = open('Log.txt','a')
    def __init__(self):
            self.f = open('Log.txt', 'a')
            self.f.write("My Program Started at "+str(datetime.datetime.now())+"\n")
    def __del__(self):
            self.f.write("closing the log file and terminating...")
            self.f.close()
```

my code works, but as you see above I have two f=open('Log.txt','a')

is there any way to avoid that ?
I tried to delete one of them but it would yell at me... is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Why does your class have two `__init__`s?

Comment: `it would yell at me` is a vague way to describe a programming problem. Be precise. Please.

Comment: oops, sorry I it was supposed to be typde __del__

Comment: Which one did you delete?

Comment: we need error messages

Comment: This isn't Java, you don't need the first `f = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have only one.

The `first f=...` creates the file handler as a **class attribute** at import time, so the first time you instantiate MyClass you have the handler open, but:

```
MyClass() # and __del__ is called here
MyClass() # f is closed
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

If you do it at the `__init__` method creates the handler as a **instance attribute** and opens the file every time you instantiate MyClass(), probably this is what you want, except if you want to use the class without instantiating it.

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
class Test:
  def __init__(self): #open the file
    self.f=open("log.txt", "w") #or "a"
  def mywrite(self, mytext): #write the text you want
    self.f.write("%s\n" % mytext)
  def myclose(self): #close the file when necessary (you don't need to delete the object)
    self.f.close()

myFile=Test()
myFile.mywrite("abcd")
myFile.myclose()
```